# tfrecord: print image from .tfrecord file

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-datasets

I created a dataset from scratch for my tensorflow model. Im am working with TensorFlow 2.4.0. For acceleration I decided to store the data in a .tfrecord file type, now I want to check if it stored right in the .tfrecord file.
I wrote a code to print one image inside the .tfrecord file, but I get following error:

```
    imageRaw = imageFeautre['image/width'].numpy()
TypeError: 'TakeDataset' object is not subscriptable
```

I oriented myself on the official tensorflow tutorial (https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord#write_the_tfrecord_file)

I can load the dataset and read it, the content is correct. I cannot print one image inside it, I just want to print one image within it I found no solution on the web.

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import IPython.display as display





  tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
  tfrecordPath='/home/adem/PycharmProjects/dcganAlgorithmus/dataHandler/preparedData/train.tfrecord'



rfrecordDataSet=tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecordPath)


imageFeatureDescription ={
    'image/width:':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64),
    'image/height':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/xmin':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'image/ymin':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64),
    'image/xmax':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64),
    'image/ymin':tf.io.FixedLenFeature([],tf.int64),
}


def _parse_image_function(example_proto):
  # Parse the input tf.train.Example proto using the dictionary above.
  return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, imageFeatureDescription)



ParsedImageDataset = rfrecordDataSet.map(_parse_image_function)
imageFeautre=ParsedImageDataset.take(1)
imageRaw = imageFeautre['image/width'].numpy()
display.display(display.Image(data=imageRaw))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mentioned printing the image, but your example shows extracting the width. Here is an example that shows both.

```
feature_description = {
    'image/width': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64, default_value=0),
    'image/encoded': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string, default_value=''),
    ...
}

tfrecord_file = 'myfile.tfrecord'
raw_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(tfrecord_file)
for raw_record in raw_dataset.take(num_records_to_plot):
    example = tf.train.Example()
    example.ParseFromString(raw_record.numpy())
    record = tf.io.parse_single_example(raw_record, feature_description)

    width = record['image/width'].numpy()
    image = record['image/encoded'] 

    # Convert image from raw bytes to numpy array
    image_decoded = tf.image.decode_image(image)
    image_decoded_np = image_decoded.numpy()
    ....
```

You may also want to make sure that you are storing a valid width. Here is how I am creating the TFRecord:

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open(file_path)
image_w, image_h = im.size

with tf.io.gfile.GFile(file_path, 'rb') as fid: 
    encoded_jpg = fid.read()

tf_example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
    'image/width': dataset_util.int64_feature(image_w),
    'image/encoded': dataset_util.bytes_feature(encoded_jpg),
    ...
} 
writer.write(tf_example.SerializeToString())
``
```